# Display json_encode array from ajax result

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this result

`{"policy":[{"id":"1","policy_name":"Policy 1","description":"Testing","status":"Active","valid_until":"2022-05-18","tags":"Test","active":"0","date_added":"2022-05-18 05:36:02"}]}`

And I want to display the `policy_name` from the array and I've tried to alert it using this `alert(response['policy'].policy_name);` but I have an error.

`43:4801 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'policy_name')`

### Updated

This is my whole code:

***AJAX***

```
$("*[id^='pol_action']").each(function() {
            $(this).change(function(){ 
                var value = $(this).val();
                var id = $('option:selected', this).attr('r-id');
               

                if($(this).val() == 'edit')
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/leads/getPolData",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function(response){
                            
                        $('#update_policy_modal').modal('show');
                            alert(response['policy'].policy_name);
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                            error: function(data){
                                console.log('error');
                            }
                    });
                }
                else if ($(this).val() == 'delete')
                {
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

***Controller***

```
public function getPolData()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        
        $policy = $this->leads_model->getDataPol($id);
        $this->page_data['policy'] = $policy;

        echo json_encode($this->page_data);
    }
```

***Model***

```
public function getDataPol($id)
    {
        $where = array(
            'id'       => $id,
          );

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tblpolicies');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the result as JSON and not as a string? Could you show us your code so we better understand what's happening?

Comment: What code is causing that error?

Comment: @PierreDemessence I updated my question with controller function

Comment: @Don'tPanic I updated my question with controller function

Comment: in your Ajax call throw in a `dataType:'json'` and it should work. if not see what `console.dir(response)` spits out to learn how response looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding dataType: "JSON" so you don't have to parse JSON, like below. Then you can try to loop through the array of data:

```
$.ajax({
   url: ...,
   type: "POST",
   data: {id:id},
   dataType: "JSON"
   success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
          alert(value.policy_name);
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but I've got ```undefined```, added ```dataType: "JSON"``` on my code and use ```alert(response['policy'][0].policy_name);``` I've got what I need. The policy_name. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help! Always remember to add dataType: "JSON" when you are getting JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax call, try json parsing and then alert the field:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/leads/getPolData",
          type: "POST",
          data: {id: id},
          success: function(response){
                $('#update_policy_modal').modal('show');
                var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                alert(obj.policy[0].policy_name);
                console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(data){
                console.log('error');
          }
      });
```

I edited the answer, the below was for Javascript:

```
var json = '{"policy":[{"id":"1","policy_name":"Policy 1","description":"Testing","status":"Active","valid_until":"2022-05-18","tags":"Test","active":"0","date_added":"2022-05-18 05:36:02"}]}';

const obj= JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.policy[0].policy_name);
```

Comment: I've got an error with ```VM2293:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the token "o" is?

Comment: I updated my question with controller  and ajax function

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an array so it should be:

```js
response['policy'][0].policy_name
```

Comment: Yes i've tried this as well but I've got and error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')```